# Absoluteness and categories

Tags: set-theory, category-theory, model-theory

From the wikipedia article on the [Skolem paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_paradox):

> A central goal of early research into set theory was to find a first order axiomatisation for set theory which was *categorical*, meaning that the axioms would have exactly one model, consisting of all sets. Skolem's result showed this is not possible, creating doubts about the use of set theory as a foundation of mathematics.

I would like to know if the term "categorical" for that property here lead to the naming of category theory. Maybe because all the problems of non-absoluteness don't happen there? How is the relation?

Comment: I doubt it is related. "Category" is a common word and it appears in math in unrelated senses like many other words, e.g. Lusternik-Schnirelmann category, Baire category...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the same category as in category theory.

This is a model theoretic concept of categoricity. We say that a theory is categorical if it has exactly one model up to isomorphism. We know that a first-order theory is categorical if and only if its only model is finite.

So for first-order theories we have a weaker notion, $\kappa$-categorical, namely all models of cardinality $\kappa$ are isomorphic.

Skolem's paradox showed that ZFC is not categorical, in the model-theoretical sense of the word, although historically I am not sure if the term was coined at the time.

On the other hand, category theory deals with notions of categorizing mathematical objects, "groups" or "compact topological rings".

Comment: Thanks. But is it true what I guessed, that there are no absoluteness analog problems in category theory? If that makes sense.

Comment: I have no idea about absoluteness in categories. At least not in the sense of set theoretical absoluteness (e.g. $\varphi$ is true in the large universe if and only if it is true in a smaller one; $\Delta_0$ etc.)

Comment: Note that Zermelo proved a quasi-categoricity result for $\mathrm{ZFC}_2$, ZFC formulated in second order logic: the models of $\mathrm{ZFC}_2$ are all and only those $V_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: @Benedict: Interesting, a although reasonable theorem. Either way, second-order set theory is a philosophically weird creature since second-order logic requires a notion of sets to exists, and at least in modern times we define sets as elements of a universe of set theory...

Comment: @Asaf you can construe the second-order part as being about classes rather than sets, although of course there are still well-known philosophical difficulties with that. In any case, the proof is in Zermelo's 1930 paper 'On Boundary Numbers and Domains of Sets'.